# OTP Generator for Salesforce Communities

Tags: apex, community, appexchange, sms

We are using Salesforce Community cloud. We have a requirement to generate One Time Password (OTP) and send to email when the user changes his mobile no. Similarly we need to generate OTP and send to mobile when the user changes his email id.  Should we be using 3rd party sms apps (Twilio, ExactTarget) and code the OTP generation and handling part in our Apex/VF? Are there any pre-built apps for this full scenario?

Comment: OTP is not a very common acronym in this space... are you referring to [One Time Password](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=add_time_based_token.htm&type=0) generation?

Comment: There are some common algos available for OTP generation. Check on the basis of digits required. There are diff methods for four and six digits. Some are on the basis of time and session ID, while some others use some user reference ID in the mix. You would need Apex to generate these and then make an API call to your SMS vendor to send it out..

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes. I am referring to One Time Passwords. Have editted my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prabha, Am not aware about if there is any pre built framework or tool which can help you but yes for Mobile integration there is a SDK available in twilio, which you can use that.

You can take a look on below link, which will describe you an OTP flow with user login, but this is on login flow side:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SMS-2FA